# dbf to excel format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel, dbf

I have a .dbf file from arcgis 10.1 and it contains 370 columns and 582 rows. I want to open it in excel but it can only open 256 columns no more than that.

There's a way that I can break a file and then merge them but that's quite time consuming.

I've got to know that by using VBA we can read dbf files the way is it. Anybody please suggest me what to do to open it in one excel sheet through VBA or any other way.

Comment: Have you tried to drag and drop the .dbf file into excel directly?

Comment: Yes and the issue remains the same, it will only show 256 columns.

Comment: Open in ArcMap, select all rows, Copy-Paste to Excel by clicking one of the small grey Squares to the left in the attribute table. Or do want to open the actual dbf table in Excel?

Comment: I want to open the dbf in excel mainly, it is limitation of arcgis that it can't plot more than 256 columns. I am trying to find way to open all the column in excel

Comment: Another way would be to use the Make Feature Layer (or Make table view) tool in ArcMap and display only the missing columns. But then you will of course not see all 370 columns.

Comment: Isn't there a 255 column limit to the dBase format (see http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007920)?  Assuming so, how is it possible that you have a 370 column DBF in ArcGIS?

Comment: There's a limit with dbf or csv file, but you can open any format table in arcgis with no limitation of columns and rows, limitations occurs with other softwares like excel. That's why export your file as text and then open in excel.

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to use python, simpledbf (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpledbf/0.2.4) can read the dbf file and export to a csv:

```
dbf = Dbf5('example.dbf')

dbf.to_csv('example.csv')
```

Comment: alternatively, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25125/saving-dbf-as-xls-using-python?rq=1

Comment: I like the simpledbf python module, not heard of that before, just had a play, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use GDAL ogr2ogr -f "XLSX" or "CSV" name.xlsx/csv source.shp

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html

Answer (score 0):

There's another way of doing it. Add the dbf file in arcgis and then export as text, then there won't be any limitation for the columns. Open in excel and simply use delimited to remove the commas.